# Can you pass a TreeController between views?

Tags: core-data, cocoa-bindings, nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller

I have a standard Master-Detail Interface and I'm using Coredata and cocoa bindings.

The Master list uses a NSOutlineView and a NSTreeController, these items remain static but different details views are swapped in and out.

So, **how do I set the content of the array controllers in the different detail views to correspond to the selection in the outlineview in the Masterview?**

This is straight forward if all the array/treecontrollers are in the same .xib file.  initially, I tried creating an Outlet from of the Treecontroller and passing this to the orther views as they are created, but I don't think this is correct.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array controller or a tree controller for as many views as you like. In your specific example, I would make the masterview owner of the tree-controller (unless you have a compelling reason to go yet another level up). Then each detail view that gets swapped-in would also have view controllers. That controller would have an assignable "tree-controller" property that would get set before its view is loaded to the value of the "master" tree-controller. Within the Nib files you can use bindings (to the tree-controller of files-owner) as you normally would.